# where is LD_LIBRARY_PATH? how do I set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable?

Tags: environment-variables

I am trying to build a c++ program using Unix.

I got the error

```
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/ME
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_regex-mt
```

I heard that I just need to set the location of libboost* in my LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable and then invoke make as I originally did, by typing

```
-L /usr/lib64 -l boost_regex-mt
```

or

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib64
```

But where is LD_LIBRARY_PATH? how do I set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable?

Comment: Why did you edit out most of your question while it was providing some useful context to understand your issue?

Comment: @jlliagre I agree: without the context supplied by the original question, the top-voted answer makes no sense.  I rolled it back.

Answer (score 39):

> how do I set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable?

You already set it when you did this:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib64
```

But that will not solve your problem. `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is consulted at time of execution, to provide a list of additional directories in which to search for dynamically linkable libraries. It is not consulted at link time (except maybe for locating libraries required by the built tools themselves!).

In order to tell the linker where to find libraries at build time, you need to use the `-L` linker option. You already did that too:

```
-L /usr/lib64
```

If you are still getting the error, then you need to make sure that the library is actually there. Do you have a file `libboost_regex-mt.so` or `libboost_regex-mt.a` in that (or any) directory? Note that a file like `libboost_regex-mt.so.othersuffix` doesn't count for this purpose. If you don't have that, then you probably need to install your distribution's development package for this library.

Comment: Under Linux, according to the ld(1) man page, `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is also consulted by `ld`: « 5. For a native linker, search the contents of the environment variable "LD_LIBRARY_PATH". »

Comment: @csx - what's your distro? Ubuntu, Fedora, CentOS, etc? See here, for eg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874220/setting-up-linked-libraries-on-linux

Comment: @vinc17, That quote from the `ld` manpage only concerns recursive dependencies: dependent libraries of a library that was already selected to be linked in. It doesn't concern finding libraries for the executable being built. That's what `-L` does.

Comment: @csx I don't know anything about scientific linux, but if `apt-get` gives you command not found then it's not Debian derived so you need another method to install the missing package. That's definitely what your problem is though.

Comment: Late but: `-Ldir -llib` should work as arguments to `ld` or to `gcc/g++/etc` when including link phase, but original&restored Q mentions `make`: with a normal makefile you probably need `LDFLAGS="whatever"` and with a clever makefile you may need almost anything, including bricks to throw at the clever makefile author.

Answer (score 21):

Another way to permanently add new path in LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

Edit `.conf` file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`.

I have ever installed an application and its libraries couldn't be recognized by another application.
Then I add the path, i.e `/usr/local/hdf5/lib`, to `x86_64-linux-gnu.conf` file. Just put in the next line. Save.

Then run `sudo ldconfig`

It worked.

PS: OS Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 5):

You can set it in your `~/.profile` and/or specific init file of your shell (e.g. `~/.bashrc` for bash, `~/.zshenv` for zsh). Then you need to restart your shell (and possibly log out and log in again, depending on your choice).

You can check your settings with:

```
env | grep '^LD_LIBRARY_PATH'
```

EDIT: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is for shared libraries that contain machine code, whose filenames typically contain `.so` in their name, possibly followed by numbers separated by periods in order to distinguish different versions. It is possible that despite `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, a library is not found because of ABI mismatch. Note also that languages (like Perl and Python) and packages may have their own system of libraries (possibly also with `.so` files), unrelated to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: My compiled program still complains about not finding a python library although I see the correct path using env | grep '^LD_LIBRARY_PATH'. What could be the issue?

Comment: @HermanToothrot I've updated my answer. Note that python has its own system of libraries. I suspect that it does not use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (to avoid collisions with the usual libraries). You need to ask a specific question for this, with the error message you get.

Answer (score 3):

If your library path error is in the linker, during compile, you need to add the path to the library into the variable $LD_LIBRARY_PATH. If the library error is when you actually run the compiled program then you need to add the library path to  /etc/ld.so.conf and run ldconfig to rebuild the library search path cache.

Comment: this worked great! My conf file points to this directory /etc/ld.so.conf.d so just add a file with your libs path to that folder. also make sure to run ldconfig as root (or sudo it)

Answer (score 3):

Solved with:

add into `/etc/systemd/system/pm2-node.service`

```
Environment=PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/app/nodejs/local/nvm/versions/node/v7.8.0/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
Environment=PM2_HOME=/home/node/.pm2
Environment=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2
Environment=OCI_LIB_DIR=/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2
```

Comment: you must restart node app with update-env flag. 'pm2 start yourapp --update-env'