# Compiling executable locally (Not system-wide)

Tags: fedora, root, ldconfig

I am working on an **Fedora-34** ssh server and I don't have root access. So I was trying to compile and install the following tool:

```
% git clone https://github.com/google/sentencepiece.git 
% cd sentencepiece
% mkdir build
% cd build
% cmake ..
% make -j $(nproc)
% sudo make install
% sudo ldconfig -v
```

For the last two lines I couldn't use sudo. So what I did is that I created a `bin` folder in my `$HOME`, and again run the following:

```
% git clone https://github.com/google/sentencepiece.git 
% cd sentencepiece
% mkdir build
% cd build
% cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=$HOME/bin/
% make -j $(nproc)
% make install
% ldconfig -v
```

However, when I run the last command I get the below error:

```
ldconfig: Can't create temporary cache file /etc/ld.so.cache~: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ldconfig` is a command which updates the system-wide cache of libraries, it can be run only by root/sudo. Doesn't your application work without it? If it doesn't please use [where is LD_LIBRARY_PATH? how do I set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168340/where-is-ld-library-path-how-do-i-set-the-ld-library-path-env-variable)